# Git problems in Azure DevOps Pipeline (CI)

Tags: git, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to update the version in a .nuspec and .PSD1 file and add a comment to README.MD during the build.

I've been following [this](https://medium.com/@jsrice7391/creating-a-nuget-build-pipeline-for-powershell-modules-within-vsts-cb75e06161e0#bafa) very helpful article that promises to deliver this goal, however, I wonder if the author, [Justin Rice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6891245/justin-rice) is making assumptions, or more likely, I don't have a clue.

I have two branches, master and develop, both local and remote. I commit and push to develop, which triggers the build.

Below is his git script, which runs after another task has modified the three files:

```
git config --global user.email "VssAdministrator@factoryvm-az459.(biib)"
git config --global user.name "VSTS Admin"
ECHO SOURCE BRANCH IS %BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH%
IF %BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH% == refs/heads/master (
   ECHO Building master branch so no merge is needed.
   EXIT
)
SET sourceBranch=origin/%BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH:refs/heads/=%
ECHO ADDING CHANGES FROM PIPELINE
git branch %sourceBranch%
ECHO ADDING MODIFIED FILES
git add --all
ECHO CREATING COMMIT
git commit -m "Changes made from Pipeline"
ECHO CHECKING MASTER
git reflog
git checkout -b master HEAD@{0}
git pull --strategy recursive -X theirs origin %BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH%
git pull --strategy recursive -X ours origin master
git add --all
git commit -m "Added from VSTS Pipeline"
git push origin master
```

The first line of issue is `git branch %sourceBranch%`. I already have a `develop` branch and `%sourceBranch%` resolves to `origin/develop`. The error is: `fatal: A branch named 'origin/develop' already exists`. I don't understand why it needs to create a new branch. I have tried with `git checkout origin/develop instead, but it doesn't help.

The next line is `git checkout -b master HEAD@{0}`. Again, I have a master branch and I receive the error `fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists.`.

I think this line is trying to create a new branch based off of the detached head (bc49db5) HEAD@{0}, but I don't really understand it. [Another article](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-checkout) (See quote below) suggests it should be the other way around: `git checkout -b HEAD@{0} master`

I've been scratching my head over this one for several days now, but to no avail. If anyone can explain what is going on or what I am doing wrong, I'd be most grateful.

P.S. The full output (With additional comments) is as follows:

```
git version 2.21.0.windows.1
====== listing branches ======
* (HEAD detached at 504cd36)
  master
  origin/develop
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
SOURCE BRANCH IS refs/heads/develop

====== ADDING CHANGES FROM PIPELINE ======
fatal: A branch named 'origin/develop' already exists.

====== ADDING MODIFIED FILES ======
====== COMMITTING ======
[detached HEAD bc49db5] Changes made from Pipeline
 3 files changed, 17 insertions(+), 15 deletions(-)
 rewrite PSAdminTools.nuspec (75%)

====== CHECKING MASTER ======
bc49db5 HEAD@{0}: commit: Changes made from Pipeline
504cd36 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from master to 504cd363ed2a7a1d9fa81ccc3a1a51790393cc27
04e8856 HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to HEAD
04e8856 HEAD@{3}: pull --strategy recursive -X theirs origin refs/heads/develop: Fast-forward
86ca92a HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from 7cf28c87edc068fb13cf1a7db3f15592fa717da3 to master
7cf28c8 HEAD@{5}: commit: Changes made from Pipeline
04e8856 HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from master to 04e88560932f8999c0f8c9a49c691901b381d036
86ca92a HEAD@{7}: reset: moving to HEAD
86ca92a HEAD@{8}: checkout: moving from a9362489e83f5b90e3b72fff990431bb6b3d9bd5 to master
a936248 HEAD@{9}: commit: Changes made from Pipeline
f85c694 HEAD@{10}: checkout: moving from master to f85c69464cdd0e9b87cd87628421e93168c5a604
86ca92a HEAD@{11}: reset: moving to HEAD
86ca92a HEAD@{12}: pull --strategy recursive -X theirs origin refs/heads/develop: Fast-forward
390d32e HEAD@{13}: checkout: moving from 8be7772ba3f03789ae8db8626d4240333d35c576 to master
8be7772 HEAD@{14}: commit: Changes made from Pipeline
86ca92a HEAD@{15}: checkout: moving from master to 86ca92a7b1ced170344a7240e6b5df95cfee36d4
390d32e HEAD@{16}: reset: moving to HEAD
390d32e HEAD@{17}: checkout: moving from 90bee5c560baf51ba69bb199750b73344d41117a to master
90bee5c HEAD@{18}: commit: Changes made from Pipeline
390d32e HEAD@{19}: checkout: moving from master to 390d32e58f9306397c917f90f57c43a795a86c09

====== Checking out master =======
fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists.

====== Pulling from their refs/heads/develop =======
From https://blah.visualstudio.com/PSAdminTools/_git/PSAdminTools
 * branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.

====== Pulling from ours master =======
From https://blah.visualstudio.com/PSAdminTools/_git/PSAdminTools
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.

====== Current branch ======
* (HEAD detached from 504cd36)
  master
  origin/develop
  pipeline

====== Adding files ======
====== Committing to master =======
HEAD detached from 504cd36
nothing to commit, working tree clean

======= Pushing to master ======
Everything up-to-date

======= Git Status =======
HEAD detached from 504cd36
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

> git checkout -b {new-branch} {existing-branch}
>
> By default git checkout -b will base the new-branch off the current HEAD. An optional additional branch parameter can be passed to git checkout. In the above example,  is passed which then bases new-branch off of existing-branch instead of the current HEAD.

### Update 20/05/2019

I seem to have got it working, although, I understand what my changes are doing, I still don't understand why these change are needed. In other words, why does the script' author's code work and mine doesn't (presuming his works).

**Change 1:**
`git branch %sourceBranch%` to `git branch -f %sourceBranch%`

**Change 2:**
`git checkout -b master HEAD@{0}` to `git checkout -B master HEAD@{0}`

My initial working state has two branches: `master` and `develop`, both local and remote.

The output of `git pull --strategy recursive -X theirs origin %BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH%` still says `Already up to date.`

The output of `git commit -m "Added from VSTS Pipeline"` says `nothing to commit, working tree clean`.

I'm not adding this update to the answer as although I'm unblocked, I still want to understand what is going on. i.e. I haven't answered my question.